# swing create font

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have some custom components with overriden `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. In some components `drawString()` method from `Graphics g` object is used.
I want to define custom fonts for such drawn strings.

I have *.ttf files with true type fonts definitions.
I have a css file with style classes, defining fonts like:

```
.rosTexLogoTitle {
   -fx-font: bold 20pt 'Tahoma Bold';
   -fx-text-fill: #246db6;
   -fx-font-weight: heavybold;
   -fx-padding: 0 10 0 0
```

I want to define all properties from css in my java class or maybe there is a way to use styles directly from css-files(not necessary).

I've tried to create font with a constructor with Map parameter:

```
public Font(Map<? extends Attribute, ?> attributes) {
}
```

But I didn't success.
I can create custom font with `Font.createFont(style, path)` then can derive it to set size. Color can be set in `Graphics.setColor()`. But I can't set 'Tahoma Bold'.

Comment: How to set all font attributes(i have them in css) properly.
Create font from *.ttf, then derive and set size, and set color to graphics? How to set font-weight? How to set family? How to work with Font constructor, which takes attributes Map?
Another part of question is about smoothing this text, but I mean to create another question mb?

Comment: When I asked *"What is your question?"* I meant a **single** question, as opposed to 5 of them.  Pick your favorite.

Comment: How to work with Font constructor, which takes attributes Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the font weight or family; these are just used to select the correct `.ttf` file.

So the solution is to use the correct `.ttf` file to begin with. For example, the font family `Arial` comes in four files:

```
arialbd.ttf - Weight "Bold"
arialbi.ttf - Weight "Bold", Slant "Italic"
ariali.ttf  - Slant "Italic"
arial.ttf   - Plain version
```

Answer (score 1):

do u have the .ttf file? createFont(style,File) return a new Font,then u can set the Color

u can use sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames() get All OS fonts